# CREATE TABLE where multiple columns are inserted with same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, create-table

Lets say I have a CREATE TABLE code like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  SortIndex int,
  Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

I was wondering if it's possible to make a table in MSSQL which had the ability to insert the ID's value into the SortIndex column when I run an INSERT.

So I would run this INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO Test (Name) VALUES ('Awesome Dude');
```

Which would normally yield the row:

```
ID,SortIndex,Name
1,NULL,"Awesome Dude"
```

But I'd like it to automatically be:

```
ID,SortIndex,Name
1,1,"Awesome Dude"
```

Is this even possible by altering the CREATE TABLE script, or do I have to use a TRIGGER?

Comment: In this case, what does the sortindex column give you that the ID doesn't?

Comment: A trigger would be the way to go

Comment: @DavidG it gives him the ability to update it. It's a sorting key that can be changed I would expect from the name.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen That's correct :)

Comment: You can use NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) on both the cols

Comment: Default value would be worth a shot.

Comment: With a trigger you may run into some really fun concurrency issues.

Comment: @DanBracuk A default value wouldn't increment

Comment: @DavidG What do you mean by concurrency issues? (I'm sorta new to this)

Comment: @PDNagilum For example, what happens if two INSERTs happen at the same time, which one gets the highest value for sort order?

Comment: @DavidG but wouldn't the trigger automatically know the identity of the insert that triggered it? So in the case of two inserts happening at the same time, two triggers are triggered, one for each row. Or am I terribly in the wrong here?

Comment: @PDNagilum So you want the sortindex to default to the same value as the ID?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, that's the idea. But I want to be able to override it at a later time, so It should only get the same value as ID upon the initial INSERT.

Comment: @PDNagilum Then I would go with GarethD's answer (and don't forget to upvote and accept his answer!)

Comment: @DavidG, a default value would not increment if you made it a constant.  My idea was to default it to the value of the id.  I don't know if it would work, but it wouldn't take long to find out.

Comment: @DanBracuk A default value for a column can only be a constant value and can't use other database objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclided to take a slightly different approach to this. If you want your SortIndex to default to the ID, but be overridable, I would use a nullable column, and a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  OverrideSortIndex int,
  Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
  SortIndex AS ISNULL(OverrideSortIndex, ID)
);
```

If you need to change the sort index for any reason, update the column `OverrideSortIndex` and this takes precedence.

Comment: Oh, I like this approach.

Comment: I've never seen it done like this. I'm gonna have to try this one out. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried out this approach and it's working perfectly. Thanks :)